# I was solving a 'valid pair' problem on CodeChef which is working fine on STS Workspace but I'm getting a runtime error on CodeChef

Tags: java

This is the error that I am encountering

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
at Codeche.main(Main.java:13)
```

Below is the following code.

```
/* package codechef; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Codechef
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        String S;
        int A,B,C;
        S=in.nextLine();
        String arr[]=S.split(" ");
        A=Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
        B=Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
        C=Integer.parseInt(arr[2]);
        if(A>=1 && A<=10 && B>=1 && B<=10 && C>=1 && C<=10)
        {
            if(A==B || A==C || B==C)
                System.out.println("Yes");
            else
                System.out.println("No");
            in.close();
        }
    }
}
```

The code is working fine on STS Workspace but I'm unable to run this on CodeChef

Comment: Maybe contact the site administrator, Stack Overflow is not an external help desk. We can hardly help you here.

Comment: @Lino , can you suggest me some changes in this code which won't result in an error. Because I'm unable to make any submissions.

Comment: Google `"NoSuchElementException: No line found"` (with the quotes)  and you'll find a number of threads started by others who have gotten the same error.  Add `"Code Chef"` to the search and you'll get some threads specifically about having this problem there.

Comment: BTW, you should not use uppercase identifier names for variables. Use lowercase.  There are a number of commonly used coding convention documents out there, but they all agree on this point.  The Google style guide is a good one to use: https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5-naming

Answer (score 1):

This problem seems to be due to the fact that the Code Chef platform is not providing a standard input source to your program like most execution environments provide.  In other words, `System.in` is not an open input stream that can be read from. If this is not a bug in Code Chef, then the problem is either that you have not configured something on the Code Chef site correctly, or your code should not be reading from `System.in`.

You can reproduce this error in other environments by closing `System.in` and then trying to use it:

```
try {
    System.in.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
String S = in.nextLine();
```

Result:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
    at Codechef.main(Test.java:20)
```